# Why isn't Ember Data batching multiple record requests into a single HTTP request?

Tags: json, ember-data

I was expecting findByIds to optimize requests by requesting multiple records in a GET request.  Instead, in my app, Ember Data issues a separate HTTP GET request for each record, rather than bundling all the requests into a single request. I have a handlebars template displaying dozens or even hundreds of small records, and it floods the server with many HTTP requests, rather than just one.

Here's how I'm requesting the records with findByIds:

```
App.ThingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params, transition) {  
    return this.store.findByIds('thing', [4,65,22]);
  }
}
```

Here's a summary of the associated requests and responses for that find:

```
http://example.com/things/4
{"things":[{"id":"4", "name":"foo"}]}

http://example.com/things/65
{"things":[{"id":"65", "name":"bar"}]}

http://example.com/things/22
{"things":[{"id":"22", "name":"baz"}]}
```

Assuming none of the records are in the local cache, I would have expected Ember Data to issue the single request of:

```
http://example.com/things/4,65,22
```

And get back a response like this:

```
{"things":[
  {"id":"4", "name":"foo"},
  {"id":"65", "name":"bar"},
  {"id":"22", "name":"baz"}
]}
```

This is different than some of the Q&A I've seen that asks about side-loaded data in the response.

Comment: Moved my comment to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer by going through the Ember Data sources.

coalesceFindRequests needs to be set to true, not false (the default) for the RESTAdapter.

```
coalesceFindRequests: true,
```

On the server, I wanted to support two different request formats for multiple things:

```
GET /things/4,65,22 
GET /things/ids[]=4&ids[]=65&ids[]=22
```

In my routes.rb file,

```
get 'app/things/:ids'    => 'app#things', :via => :get 
get 'app/things'         => 'app#things', :via => :get
```

And had to change my controller, so that if "ids" is an array, leave as is.  If "ids" is a string, create an array by splitting by a ",".

Comment: Thank you thank you! More details here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/08/18/ember-data-1-0-beta-9-released.html#toc_hasmany-coalescing-now-opt-in